# Formatting multiple references containing the same author

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using natbib with a custom bibliography style and so would rather not change away from natbib if I can help it.  I have one author with two citations and I just want the References section to list both citations properly under the one author.  I cannot figure out how to do this as currently the output treats each citation as belonging to a different author (as a different entry). I have not provided a MWE as it does not seem necessary in this case but I can if need be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\begin{document}
Here is text \citep[p.1]{authorA}.  And then more from same author \citep[p.1]{authorB}
\clearpage
\bibliography{bib}{}
\end{document}
```

And the bib file:

```
@book{authorA,
author={Smith, John},
title={Book},
}
@book{authorB,
author={Smith, John},
title={Other Book},
}
```

I would like the "References" section at the end of the article to look something like this:

```
Smith, John. Book
------Other Book
```

Instead of like this:

```
Smith, John. Book

Smith, John. Other Book
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to interpret your objective, viz., to "list both citations properly under the one author". Please provide an MWE (minimum working example) that illustrates what you've done so far, including information about the bibliography style file you use. E.g., does it generate author-year or numerical citations? It would also be helpful if you'd provide information on the two bib items you're citing and whose references you're trying to modify.

Comment: I've added an MWE. I didn't quite answer your questions but hopefully what I added is clear as to what I'm trying to do and what is currently happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the formatting of the bibliographic entries in the References section isn't actually governed by `natbib`; `natbib` is mainly a citation management system that can handle various numeric and authoryear citation styles. The formatting of the bib entries -- including the replacement of a repeated author (or authors) by a long dash -- is determined by the bibliography style you specify.

You mention in the first paragraph of your question that you use a custom bibliography style. However, in the MWE you state that you use the bibliography style `plainnat`. The following code assumes you're working with `plainnat` and shows how the file `plainnat.bst` may be modified to achieve your typesetting objectives. Hopefully, the bibliography style you're actually working with isn't too different from `plainnat`.

1. Start by creating a copy of `plainnat.bst`; save the copy as, say, `myplainnat.bst`. (Never edit the original files.)
2. Open the file `myplainnat.bst` with your favorite text editor.
3. Locate the function `article`. (This function starts on lin 699 in my copy of `plainnat`.) *Immediately before* this function, insert the following lines of code:

   ```
   STRINGS {oldname}

   FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
   { 's :=
      oldname empty$
        { s 'oldname := s }
        { s oldname =
            { "---{}---{}---" }
            { s 'oldname := s }
           if$
        }
      if$
   }
   ```

   You didn't specify *how long* the dashes that replace the author's name (or authors' names) should be. In the code above, I use three consecutive em-dashes. Feel free to change this setup to suit your typographic needs and preferences.
4. Next, locate each of the ten [10!] instances of the following line of code in `myplainnat.bst`:

   ```
     author format.key output
   ```

   and insert the instruction

   ```
     name.or.dash
   ```

   on a line by itself *immediately following* each of the `author format.key output` lines.
5. Locate the two instances of the following five lines of code, in the functions `book` and `inbook`:

   ```
   { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
   }
   { format.authors output.nonnull
     crossref missing$
   ```

   and replace them with

   ```
   { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
     editor format.key output
     name.or.dash
    }
   { format.authors output.nonnull
     name.or.dash
     crossref missing$
   ```

   I.e., insert the instruction `name.or.dash` as indicated in each of two instances.
6. In the function `proceedings`, locate the line

   ```
   editor format.key output
   ```

   and insert the line

   ```
   name.or.dash
   ```

   immediately following that line.

   If you've made all of these edits, you should have sixteen [16] instances of the string "name.or.dash" in your `.bst` file.
7. Save the file `myplainnat.bst` either in the directory that contains your main `.tex` file or in a directory that's in the search path of your TeX distribution.
8. Be sure to use the instruction `\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}` from now on.

Happy TeXing!

Comment: Thank you so much for that -- I had given up hope. I am using a custom style and just put plainnat in the MWE since I didn't think that was where the problem was nor would anyone have my custom style so the MWE would fail for them.  Anyway, I am using a customized plainnat so your instructions remained the same and it works like a charm, thanks again!

Comment: @bfootdav - You're most welcome! I'm glad that the proposed solution meets your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding $~$ after the second name of the last (or any) author. It did work for me. I used IEEE format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While this might work, this does not look like a clean solution. Additionally, the math mode is not required here.